# Insert images into container field in FileMaker using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, filemaker

I have to insert an jpeg2000 image into a filemaker container field. I'm using Filemaker 19.
googling I found examples like this

```
INSERT INTO TestDatabase
   (LocatorNum, FileName, SampleSet, PutAs(Image, 'FILE')) VALUES ('003', '003', '003', ?)
```

But I get a syntax error.  I tryed

```
   INSERT INTO TestDatabase
   (LocatorNum, FileName, SampleSet, Image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, PutAs(?, 'JP2 '))
```

this is accepted but the result is that the container does not show the image. It shows and internal file named "noname.dat" What is the correct way ? A full example would be great.
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, `JP2 ` is not a supported file type in FileMaker SQL. See the *Claris FileMaker SQL Reference* document.